# Swap the stereo Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: sound

I installed Ubuntu 14.04, but I figure out, that the left channel is actually right and the right is left. I tried everything, from the Ubuntu forums, but without success. I'm using hp dc7600, with wired speakers, connected to the built-in sound card.